In a matroid does every singleton appear in a base?
If $\mathcal{M}=(\mathcal{S}, \mathcal{I})$ is a matroid with non-zero rank does every singleton (as a set containing only one element of $\mathcal{S}$) appears in at least one base of $\mathcal{M}$?
I tried searching for counterexamples but couldn't find any. I suppose that because Greedy works on matroids is allways possible to select that element first and then augment it to a base but I don't know how to formalize or continue that idea.

The question has been answered, but I want to comment on the greedy algorithm. It won't augment every element to a base. It starts with $B = \emptyset$ and augments it with $x\in\mathcal S$ only if $B \cup x$ is independent. So already in the first step if $x$ is a loop (as defined in the answers), $\emptyset \cup x$ will not be independent and the algorithm will go to the next element.

A base consists of elements of $\mathcal{S}$, not subsets, so a singleton can never appear in a base. Did you mean to ask if every element of $\mathcal{S}$ appears in some base?

General tip: Matroid theory comes from a desire to find a general framework for dealing with phenomena in two concrete settings: finite graphs and linear algebra. When we're looking for examples in matroid theory it's good practice to look in one (or both!) of these settings to improve our intuition.
Graph theory: Given a graph $G = (E,V)$ there is a matroid $M=(E, \mathcal{C})$ whose circuits (minimal dependent sets) $\mathcal{C}$ are the circuits (minimal closed paths) in $G$. Your question in this setting becomes "Can there be an edge of a graph that is also a circuit?" Sure! Just use one edge to connect a vertex to itself. Such an edge is called a loop in graph theory. And matroid theory borrows the terminology: A loop in the graph $G$ is called a loop in the corresponding matroid $M$.
Linear algebra: Given a finite collection of vectors $X$ in a vector space $V$, we get a matroid $M=(X,\mathcal{C})$ whose circuits (minimal dependent sets in the matroid theory sense) are the minimal dependent sets (in the linear algebra sense). Your question in this setting becomes: "Is there a vector in a vector space that is linear dependent?" Yes! And there is only one in any vector space: the zero vector. In any vector matroid, a loop corresponds to the zero vector.
In general, a loop in a matroid $M$ is any element $e$ of $M$ such that $\{e\}$ is a circuit in $M$. Here's how to tell if your matroid has a loop.
Proposition: Let $M$ be a matroid and $e$ be an element of $M$. Then the following are equivalent:

$e$ is a loop in $M$;
$\{e\}$ is a circuit of $M$;
$e$ is an element of no basis of $M$;
$e$ is an element of no independent set of $M$; and
$e$ is an element of every hyperplane of $M$.


Not necessarily. A matroid can have a loop. A loop in a matroid $\mathcal{M} = (\mathcal{S},\mathcal{I})$ is an element $e\in \mathcal{S}$ that is not contained in any base. Equivalently, $\{e\}$ is a circuit, or $\{e\}$ has rank $r_{\mathcal{M}}(\{e\}) = 0$, or in particular, a loop is not independent, i.e., $\{e\}\not\in\mathcal{I}$. Thus the augmentation axiom to which you are referring (which only applies to independent sets) does not apply.
